# How do I re-order file content to implement simple obfuscation

Tags: linux, bash, encoding

If I have some files that have a recognizable signature e.g. [Magic Number](http://www.linfo.org/magic_number.html), they are recognized in Nautilus as a Document, Video or Audio regardless of suffix.

If I want to encode them without the encoded file itself being recognized as being encoded, one simple strategy could be to re-order the file contents in blocks:

For example, if the file is split into 10 equally sized blocks (any remainder can be left behind as a variable sized 11th block, `K`) `ABCDEFGHIJK`, a simple encoding would rearrange the block order: e.g.
`block_encode input_file output_file` 
would result in an output file organized as: `BADCFEHGJIK`.
(Of course, I could also just swap the "last half" and the "first half" around, leaving perhaps 1 byte unmoved at the end of the file).

In this case, decoding would be achieved by simply applying the encoding again.

The resulting file would most likely not be recognized as any valid document, video, audio, etc.

My question is: Is there any neat (simple) way of implementing this in bash, using standard tools (e.g. `dd` )? (I could write a C program, if required).

A followup would be: If the file were a media file, how could I stream the "decoded" content to, for example, VLC, without having to save the decoded stream as a file first?

Comment: Why not just use a proper encryption program?

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? Reordering file contents provides next to zero security.

Comment: My primary reason for not using a proper encryption algorithm is to not make it obvious that the file has been encrypted. Encrypted files are recognizably encrypted, where-as the garbled file is "just a file".

Comment: @KevinM It's also "just decipherable". If you want to encrypt: encrypt. If not: don't bother in the first place.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers Indeed, but I don't want encryption. Sorry, the question title does not match the content. I've tried to make that clearer in the question body.

Comment: Hi, i'm currently wondering the same thing, reorder file content, have you find any tools or a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I briefly considered using `dd` in a script, to do 'in-line' content re-ordering in a script. If you're interested, I can play with this and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a simple XOR with a well-known key. It'll splat any magic numbers in the file, defeating `file`(1), and operates sequentially so it dead simple to code as well as stream over stdin/stdout. If you pick a nice short XOR key (eg 4 octets) the output file will have similar entropy to the source, so it's not immediately obvious that the file has been garbled: a text file so-encrypted will still compress nicely, for example, whereas the pessimal case of perfect encryption compresses not at all (which would be XOR with random bytes, key length equal to file length).

I don't quite understand the motivation for the question though! With this encoding though and the extension stripped off it will defeat most file recognition tools, but nothing else. There may well still be patterns left in the file that could be used to fingerprint it.

Comment: Defeating file recognition tools is pretty much all that I am after. As I mentioned, stripping or renaming the extension does not fool Nautilus, for example.